# A question about the addConditionWaiter method in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#ConditionObject

Tags: java

I am reading the source code AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#ConditionObject of Java 8, I got a question here:

the addConditionWaiter method in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#ConditionObject is defined as follows：

```java
private Node addConditionWaiter() {
    Node t = lastWaiter;
    // If lastWaiter is cancelled, clean out.
    if (t != null && t.waitStatus != Node.CONDITION) {
        unlinkCancelledWaiters();
        t = lastWaiter;
    }
    Node node = new Node(Thread.currentThread(), Node.CONDITION);
    if (t == null)
        firstWaiter = node;
    else
        t.nextWaiter = node;
    lastWaiter = node;
    return node;
}
```

I have a question for the following code snippet:

```java
Node t = lastWaiter;
// If lastWaiter is cancelled, clean out.
if (t != null && t.waitStatus != Node.CONDITION) {
    unlinkCancelledWaiters();
    t = lastWaiter;
}
```

The comment says: `If lastWaiter is cancelled, clean out.` ,why the if check is `t != null && t.waitStatus != Node.CONDITION`.

It checks lastWaiter's waitStatus is not Node.CONDITION, it looks it has nothing to do `If lastWaiter is cancelled, clean out.`